# Importing via sqlcmd errors out

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2014

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop> sqlcmd -S SQLMAIN\MSSQLSERVER -i rdmdb.sql
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [
87]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
 establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I opened the port 1433 to allow remote connections in the firewall. I also disabled the firewall with no success.

I double checked server name and instance and they all check out.

Comment: Remove the instance name ("\MSSQLSERVER") to connect to the default instance.  Just specify `-S SQLMAIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are really sure that your Server name is correct you can still try to specify the port explicitly like that:

```
sqlcmd -S SQLMAIN,1433 -i rdmdb.sql
```

If you run your SQL Server database as a `Contained Database` it might be necessary to login to the database direclty using `-d`:

```
sqlcmd -S SQLMAIN,1433 -d yourDatabase -i rdmdb.sql
```

Make sure that you really can access your SQL Server on the specified port. You can try this using telnet.

```
telnet SQLMAIN 1433
```

If you don't use a windows login you might need to provide your username and passowrd using `-U` (Username) and `-P` (Password).

```
sqlcmd -S SQLMAIN,1433 -d yourDatabase -U User -P Password -i rdmdb.sql
```

If you use the integrated authentication, you can also try the `Trusted Connection` using `-E`

```
sqlcmd -S SQLMAIN,1433 -d yourDatabase -E -i rdmdb.sql
```

Please be also be sure that the specified input file can be accessed and found at your specified location.

Hopefully this will answer your question and your getting your connection to work. :-)

Comment: If TELNET isn't installed, port connectivity can be checked with this powershell command: `1433 | % { echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("YourServerName",$_)) "server listening on TCP port $_" }`

Comment: Yes he is right. This can also be a solution. But it can also be enabled on Windows 8/8.1 or Windows Server. :-) Upvoted your comment.